# Dynamic WebProject import another project and dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-indigo

I have a dynamic web Project which we will call "project A" and another regular java project which we will call "project B" in eclipse. I have added project b to B to project A by going into project properties 
`Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Project`. 
This works and adds the jar "project B.jar" to the project A/WEB-INF/lib folder. However the external jar files configured on "project B" are not included in "project B.jar". Additionally i have gone to 
`project b -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` 
and i have checked all required dependencies for "project B" and it still does not include them in the jar. How can i get eclipse to include these jars in the "project B.jar" file.

If you need to know I'm using eclipse Indigo and we are not using mavin for this project its only this one jar we need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn project B into the faceted form (go to the project properties, "Project Facets" -> "Convert to faceted form..."). The only facets required are "Java" and "Utility Module". If I remember correctly, at that point Eclipse gives you a warning that those additional JAR dependencies may be missing at runtime of project A, giving you the quick fix option to add them as dependencies. This will add an `attributes` element to the .classpath file of project B for each referenced JAR file, for example like this:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar">
   <attributes>
      <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="../"/>
   </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

JARs that don't have to be included will get this attribute instead:

```
<attributes>
   <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
</attributes>
```

If you don't get said warnings, you might be able to just add the `attributes` element directly. Note: this is all for Eclipse Luna, but I know at least in Kepler it already worked like this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Hein. "Project B" is a faceted project and it has the Utility Module selected. However my .classpath file does not look like the provided. Mine all look like 
`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/.../commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>`
and have no attributes fields. If i add them manually what should the `value="../"/>` value be ?

Comment: You should be able to just leave it like that, i.e. `value="../"`. At least that works for me with my dynamic web projects. I found those two threads that confuse me because it seems like I should be using `value="/WEB-INF/lib"` because I also have a standalone web project: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/172866/ https://wiki.eclipse.org/ClasspathEntriesPublishExportSupport. But that `"../"` entry is what Eclipse created for me and which works.

Comment: Thanks again @Hein editing my classpath on project B and adding the entries worked.

Comment: By the way, I could not make Eclipse recognize a change in the Utility Project (Project B in your example) automatically, so that if Project A is deployed on an application server (GlassFish in my case), Eclipse marks it as "Republish" and allows you to do just that. My workaround is to run "Clean" on Project A, which always triggers "Republish", also pulling in any potential changes from Project B. Never found out if that is a bug or if my setup is broken.